# thymeleaf - combined th:each with th:href

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm new to Thymeleaf (and webdev) and I'm trying to combine Thymeleaf iteration (th:each) with URL re-writing (th:href).

```
<a th:each="lid : ${lists}" th:text="${lid}" th:href="@{/list?l=${lid}}">
hello
</a>
```

This produces the following (where lid=45):

```
<a href="/list?l=${lid}">45</a>
```

So, it did the substitution on the th:text, but not on the th:href.

I'm not trying to do any sort of URL re-writing, I'm just using the '@' syntax because I want Thymeleaf to substitute the 'lid' attribute.

I'm using the current version of Thymeleaf (2.1.2) with Google App Engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to do any url rewriting, you shouldn't use the `@` syntax.

You can use the pipeline (`|`) syntax to do some literal substitions:

```
th:href="|/list?l=${lid}|"
```

Source: [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions)

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this way:

```
<a th:href="@{'/list?l=' + ${lid}}" th:text="${lid}">element</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment on a previous post but the Thymeleaf Source documentation link from a previous post is broken.  Documentation can now be found at the following link:

[Thymeleaf Standard URL Syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

Section 9 Using Expressions in URLs in this documentation explains how you can use expressions within other expressions when generating URLs with the @ syntax.  The following is an example:

```
<a th:href="@{/order/details(id=${modelattribute})}"/>
```

Will produce a link similar to:

```
http://domain.org/context/order/details?id=1
```

if modelattribute had a value of 1 in the current context.

Comment: Following the link I ended up using: `th:href="@{main/{sectionId}(sectionId=${section.id})}`, which substitutes `sectionId` with `${section.id}`, giving an output of e.g. `main/12345`