# Thymeleaf th:each not working with href

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am newbie in Thymeleaf. I am unable to show data using th:each

I want to show this data

categoryDaoImpl.java

```
static {
        Category category=new Category();

        category.setId(1);
        category.setName("Television");
        category.setDescription("This is first Television in our home.");
        category.setImageURL("rashed.jpg");
        category.setActive(true);

        categories.add(category);
}
```

in my controller mycontroller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/","/home","/index"})
public String showHome(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("categories",categoryDao.list());
    return "home";
}
```

and this my html page where I want to show data.

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a th:each="category : ${categories}" th:text="${category}" th:href="#" class="list-group-item active">Home</a>
</div>
```

One more information, those html code don't show in

> **page source**

I also try this solution [thymeleaf - combined th:each with th:href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962011/thymeleaf-combined-theach-with-thhref) . 
But it didn't work in my html file and I am also using bootstrap 4. how can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is happening?

Comment: it doesn't show any data which is come with categories.

Comment: maybe `category` is empty. It would be nice to include generated html as well. How can we help you if you does not provide minimum ammount of information like input -output and expected output.

Comment: look at my updated question, one more think is,  those code don't show in "inspect" or "page source" which means at least don't work in browser, how can fix that?

Comment: Can you post the code for the list function in categorydaoimpl class?

Answer (score 0):

one error that you have in your html code is that in the th:text you should have the Description attribute (most probably) and not the object category
so you need the following

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a th:each="category : ${categories}" th:text="${category.description}" th:href="#" class="list-group-item active">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this approch earlier, but didn't work. And one more information, when I open the "page source" then don't show any code that means these code are not working properly. I assume that, if these html code show then work properly in my project but nothing happening here.